# PHP cURL passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

I have the following cURL PHP function that works correctly

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/api",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api\"\r\n\r\n123344\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    ),
));
```

I would like to build the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS by hand so have tried to pass an array instead like so...

```
$data = array('api'=>'123344');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/api",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    ),
));
```

But this is not giving me any response, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php: _"If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data`."_ So don't do this yourself, let cURL handle it.

Comment: Thank you, I had read that but wrongly assumed I could leave it set manually.  All working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php:

> If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data`.

So don't do this yourself, let cURL handle it.

It knows how `multipart/form-data` works, and will create the request body including the boundaries for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also  http_build_query() for your post data

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
```